# 代入時のカンマの意味

Tags: python

ゼロから作るdeep learning 2のサンプルコードに関しての質問です。
https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch-2/blob/master/common/layers.py

下記のコードに `W, = self.params` という箇所がありますが、`W,` のカンマの意味がわかりません。複数代入する以外の使い方があるのでしょうか？

```
class MatMul:
def __init__(self, W):
    self.params = [W]
    self.grads = [np.zeros_like(W)]
    self.x = None

def forward(self, x):
    W, = self.params　　　#この部分
    out = np.dot(x, W)
    self.x = x
    return out

def backward(self, dout):
    W, = self.params　　　　#この部分
    dx = np.dot(dout, W.T)
    dW = np.dot(self.x.T, dout)
    self.grads[0][...] = dW
    return dx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これはスライス表記というやつで、以下のように(タプルのような)シーケンスの要素に代入するという意味です:

```
(W,) = self.params
```

質問の例だと以下と同義です:

```
W = self.params[0]
```

ただし↑との挙動の違いとして「代入文の左辺と右辺の要素数が同じでなければならない(この場合1個でなければならない)」という条件があります。
この要素数が増えると、以下のような(よく目にする)表記になります:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: とてもわかりやすい説明ありがとうございました